# Pass custom data to FBA Membership Provider

Tags: claims-based-auth

I need to have some additional data sent to each call to my membership provider.  For example SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser takes a URI, a username and a password.  The username and password are passed through to the Security Token Service (over WCF), and ultimately to my MembershipProvider implementation.  I need to pass some additional context information to my MembershipProvider.  One idea is to add a header to the OperationContext outgoing message headers and then inspect the incoming message headers in my Membership Provider.  The problem is that there is not OperationContext available for me to send the headers before the call to AuthenticateFormsUser.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I also have a similar requirement. Please let me know if you got answer to this. Also could you please explain how it is possible using "OperationContext". Thanks

Comment: I have almost the same scenario where I want to user some sort of Custom data for my role provider. Actually, I need a Customer Number to specifically fetch User Roles based on that customer No. If you managed to send any kind of Custom Data to Custom providers, Please Share.

Comment: What kind of context info are we talking about? Is it contextual to the site or to the user? For the user there's always the option of adding additional claims to the token.